# Is it possible to create onSnapshot listeners for an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have users...each user has multiple groups he/she is a member of.  Each users group membership is an array embedded on his/her user doc.  There is a tasks collection, each task contains an array of authorizedGroups that correspond to the user's groups.  Most tasks have just one authorizedGroup but some have a few groups. Tasks are assigned by one user to another user.

I want to query for all tasks that are available to the user and have listeners in place for each query.

Using get() has been successful but does not provide the active listener that I was hoping for. Is there a method to generate listeners for each group?  The onSnapshot method does not return a promise.  Unclear how I can achieve this goal. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
created() {
  const getTasksPerGroup = async (groups) => {
  // Make a get request using each group in users group membership list
     const queries = groups.map((group) => {
        return this.$store.state.db
             .collection('tasks')
             .where('authorizedGroups', 'array-contains', group)
             .where('taskAssignedTo', '==', this.$store.state.auth.user.displayName)
             .get()
      })

  // Use Await Promise.all to acquire an array of querySnapshots
  const result = await Promise.all(queries).then((querySnapshot) => {
     return querySnapshot.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs).reduce((acc, docs) => [...acc, ...docs])})

  //Result is an array of querySnapshots...pushing each qs.data() to the tasks array
      let tasks = []
      result.forEach((qs) => {
         let item = qs.data()
         tasks.push(item)
         console.log('tasks:', tasks)
         this.$store.commit('tasks/mutate_tasksArray', tasks)
       })
 }
  // Invoke async function that gets the user's groups array
        getTasksPerGroup(this.allFirmGroups)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `get()`, which returns a promise and gives you one set of results, or you can use `onSnapshot()` to attach a persistent listener, which does not return a promise, because only you can control when the listener stops.

If you want to listen to the results of multiple queries, you will have to add a listener to each one of them, and when you're done listening, unsubscribe the listener from each one without the help of any promises returned by the Firestore SDK.  It's up to you to determine the timing of adding and removing the listeners.